# R: How to count rows with same factor levels and a numeric in a range

Tags: r

If got data looking like this:

```
    A | B | C 
   -------------- 
    f | 1 | 1420h 
    f | 1 | 1540h 
    f | 3 | 600h 
    g | 2 | 900h 
    g | 2 | 930h 
    h | 1 | 700h 
    h | 3 | 400h
```

Now I want to create a new column which counts other rows in the data frame that meet certain conditions.

In this case I would like to know in each row how often the same combination of A and B occured in a range of 100 around C.

So the result with this data would be:

```
    A | B | C    | D
    ------------------ 
    f | 1 | 1420 | 0
    f | 1 | 1540 | 0
    f | 3 | 1321 | 0
    g | 2 | 900  | 1
    g | 2 | 930  | 1
    h | 1 | 700  | 0
    h | 3 | 400  | 0
```

I actually came to a solution using for(for()). But the time R needs to compute the resuts is tooooo long.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  df[i,D] <- sum( for(p in 1:nrow(df)) {
                                df[p,A] == df[i,A] & 
                                df[p,B] == df[i,B] & 
                                df[i,C] +100 > df[p,C] & 
                                df[p,C] > df[i,C]-100 } ) }
```

Is there a better way?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: How big is your real data? Doing a comparison of every row in a group could get realllllly big. I could guess that farming this out to sql with a self join of `df` might be quicker.

Comment: Something like data.table could be used too - `library(data.table); setDT(df); df[df, on=.(A,B), D := sum(abs(C-i.C) < 100)-1, by=.EACHI]` - but this doesn't seem super quick when the count in each group ramps up.